# ¿Cómo borrar el contenido de los edit text al cambiar a otra pantalla? Android

Tags: android

Lo que necesito es que al cambiar de pantalla, lo que tenían escrito los edittext se borre, para que cuando vuelva a la pantalla en la que se encuentran esos edit text estén vacíos. Mi aplicación es básicamente para guardar la información de los edit text.

Comment: Llevas tiempo en el sitio y aún no has realizado el [tour], tambien te sugiero revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con el metodo:

> setText()

Puedes pasarle un String para cambiar su contenido, en este caso setText("") y quedaría vacio.

Por ejemplo:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             editText.setText(""); // limpias el textfield
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);    
             startActivity(intent); // inicias la nueva activity
         }
     });
```

Comment: Me funcionó. Gracias.

Comment: En vez de dar las gracias, deberías darla por contestada! @PacoPepe. En la tachita.

Comment: @PacoPepe podrías marcar la respuesta como respondida si se ha solucionado tu problema.